# Changing echo to show on multiple lines?

Tags: php, echo

I am using the following code to only keep first 30 chars of `$prod_name`.

```
if(strlen($prod_name) > 30) {echo substr($prod_name,0,30)."...";}else {echo $prod_name;}?>
```

How do I make this appear on a newline?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You mean like echo '\n'. substr($prod_name,0,30); or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: yes!! thanks~ long weekend @brance

Comment: Read about PHP strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah the answer is

```
echo '\n'. substr($prod_name,0,30);
```

Comment: In single-quote enclosed strings only `\\ ` and `\' ` are special escaped characters. Anything else (including `\n`) is printed as-is. This means `echo('\n');` prints the characters `\ ` and `n` and not a new line. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single